# if else condition not evaluating in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I'm making a todo list app and to provide alternate colors to new todo items as they are added in the todolist i have used the if else statement in React component but i think it is not evaluating.

Below are the two classes from my css file that i'm using -->

```
 .bgColorItem1{
    background-color: white;
}

.bgColorItem2{
    background-color:grey;
}
```

Below is the component that accepts arguments item(todo item that will be added to the list) and key(index passed as key) from todolist -->

```
  import React from 'react';
    import './App.css';

    const TodoItem=({item,key})=>{
        let settingClass="";

    // *****so the problem is here in the if condn that's not putting settingClass as bgColorItem1*****     
        if(key%2===0){
            settingClass="bgColorItem1";
        }else{
        settingClass="bgColorItem2";
    }

    return <div className={`boxSpace centerAligning ${settingClass}`}>{item}</div>
}

export default TodoItem;
```

So what i expect from this code that key which was index in todolist component passed to todo here above should return 0 for even so that settingClass can have alternate values and hence provide alternate colors.But that is not the case.

Comment: how you are passing the key? Don't use key's value, use something else like index/id

Comment: You can't use the `key` prop, it reserved

Comment: `key`s have a special meaning in React, and cannot be simply read from the component props. Consider using a different term. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: `settingClass` only live in ´TodoItem´ function , your value is ´undefined´, also you dont have a return in ´TodoItem´ function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use `key`'s value since it is internal. Secondly, you can achieve like this

```
{items.map((item, index) => <TodoItem item={item} index={index} />)}
```

In `TodoItem`

```js
const TodoItem=({ item, index })=>{
        let settingClass=index % 2 === 0 ? 'bgColorItem1' : 'bgColorItem2';
    return <div className={`boxSpace centerAligning ${settingClass}`}>{item}</div>
}
```

However, you don't need react to do this, just use css, in your css

```
.boxSpace:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

.boxSpace:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `key` property as it is reserved, [also you will get a warning for it](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html):

> Warning: ListItem: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.

Simple example:

```
const ListItem = ({ key }) => {
  console.log(key);
  return <div>{key}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {[0, 1, 2, 4].map(item => (
        <ListItem key={item} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit morning-mountain-quqor]

Answer (score 0):

Your TodoItem component shouldn't have to care about the key prop, but rather a boolean (or a string if you have more than 2 styles) prop like alternateStyle:

```
const TodoItem=({item,alternateStyle})=>{
    return <div className={
                 `boxSpace centerAligning ${alternateStyle ? 'bgColorItem2' : 
                 'bgColorItem1'}`
           }>
             {item}
           </div>
```

Then you can set the value you need to alternateStyle in the parent component:

```
<div>
   {items.map((item, index) => <TodoItem item={item} alternateStyle={index % 2 !== 0} />)}
</div>
```

Comment: where is key?  key={index}      You will have an error in console when you use TodoItem in loop without key

Comment: @Max you'll have a warning if you don't use the `key` prop in a loop, but you'll still get a warning if you're using the index as the key as it's the default anyway.

Answer (score -2):

key "prop" is reserved in React. You cannot use it. Rename this props to "idx"
See: [Special props](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html)

Comment: Although the answer is correct, you should explain and elaborate on your answers as expected from SO users.

Comment: Hm... what to explain more? I wrote that it's reserved (special) prop. And of course component have no access to that prop.